# Spring Boot auto create postgresql Database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

It's possible to when I run spring-boot:run in my app, if he doesn't have the database in my postgresql the spring boot create the database?

Comment: Spring boot cannot create the database for you, what spring and ORM can do for you is to auto create the table from your entities/POJO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker-compose, run it before spring-boot.